# How to get logged in User's PermissionSetGroup id in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, permission-set-groups

I want to fetch the PermissionSetGroup assigned to current logged in user. I try to use `getRelatedListRecords` function from `lightning/uiRelatedListApi`. I have implemented the following code but I am getting some error. I try to print the error, but getting proxy in it so little unclear on the error too.

code :

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import currentUserId from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';

export default class TestComponent extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: currentUserId,
        relatedListId: 'PermissionSetAssignments',
        fields: ['PermissionSetAssignment.PermissionSetGroupId']
    })listInfo({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('line 12 ', data);
        } else if (error) {
           console.log('line 14 ',error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is:

> The related lists UI API currently does not support this related list

Unfortunately, not all objects are supported by the UI API, and this appears to be a limitation. You'll need to write Apex for this.